# How to hide some elements in a Treeview list?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, treeview

Is there a way to hide-unhide an element in the treeview list?
I need this function to handle a filter in a form.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not. But maybe you could simulate it if you try to hack it somehow.